# d3.js use a function as csv source instead of a csv path

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js, when loading data, examples I've seen so far looks like

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")...
```

I have a function that returns a dynamic server side generated csv, i use synchronous POST ajax to generate them, but for simplicity's sake lets say, I have a js function like this

```
function makeCSV(){
    return "id,value\n"+
           "0,value 1\n"+
           "1,value 2\n"+
}
```

is there a way to do something like this? and is this approach recommended at all (synchronous ajax is sure to cause lag)

```
d3.csv(makeCSV())...
```

other related concerns about CSV data loading is, is it required that .csv file is served, or would it be possible to simply put URL that makes and downloads a dynamically generated csv file, this could work as a replacement for AJAX call but manually encoding each parameter looks tedious and non-dynamic

```
d3.csv("?action=makeCSV&param1=val1&param2=val2")...
```

Comment: yes , you can do d3.csv(makeCSV(),function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.;
    });)

Comment: @NagaSaiA Of course you can, but this will result in an error because `makeCSV()` doesn't return a URL.

Comment: I just added an answer for the first part of your question, but I don't quite understand the second part about dynamically loading CSVs. Could you please be a bit more specific and add some more details. This maybe a question in its own right, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) requires the first argument be the url to load the CSV from. If you want to just parse a string containing your CSV's content no matter how this was created, you need to use [`d3.csv.parse()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) instead. For your code this would be some like this

```
var rows = d3.csv.parse(makeCSV());
```

```js
function makeCSV(){
    return "id,value\n"+
           "0,value 1\n"+
           "1,value 2\n";
}

var rows = d3.csv.parse(makeCSV())

console.log(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```